# How can I add breakpoint to internal function

Tags: c, gdb

I'm using GDB to step through the code.

The problem is my code has functions from external files. Is there a way on stepping through inner functions?

like this:

```
    int main 
    { 
    string a ="AAA"; 
    DoString(a);
    }
```

Is there a way on stepping through execution of DoString with GDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention assembly in the tags, so I assume the function is not in C. Just use **`si`** (short for `stepi`) GDB command to step one machine instruction at a time. See [the manual](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html).

Comment: Do you mean `break DoString` and then `step` doesn't work? Remember, `step` enters in the function and `next` jumps over it.

Answer (score 0):

After breaking at the function with `break DoString` , executing `step` will take you further down into the call and `next` will just *step over* it.